# using base R to convert list to dataframe while setting its class type and column names

Tags: r

There is a list like this

```
d <- list(c(1, 2, 3),
          c("20210111", "20220122", "20220302"),
          c("father", "mather", "brother"),
          c("hello", "world", "again"))
```

I want to convert it to a dataframe while setting its class type and column names. I have two vectors for it.

```
# class type
type <- c("integer", "Date", "factor", "character")
# column names
nm <- c("num", "date", "relation", "chara")
```

I try to use rapply and type.convert function to do this, but it does not work.
The result should be like this

```
# > d2
#   num       date relation chara
# 1   1 2021-01-11   father hello
# 2   2 2022-01-22   mather world
# 3   3 2022-03-02  brother again
# > str(d2)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ num     : num  1 2 3
#  $ date    : Date, format: "2021-01-11" "2022-01-22" "2022-03-02"
#  $ relation: Factor w/ 3 levels "brother","father",..: 2 3 1
#  $ chara   : chr  "hello" "world" "again"
```

How to using base R to convert list to dataframe while setting its class type and column names?

Comment: probably have to loop through your list in this case and set a a column then finalise the new columns with `data.frame()`

Comment: yep, and to reiterate: doing it _before_ converting to data.frame is better

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want this to be a *programmatic* venture:

```r
d2 <- setNames(data.frame(d), nm)
str(d2)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ num     : num  1 2 3
#  $ date    : chr  "20210111" "20220122" "20220302"
#  $ relation: chr  "father" "mather" "brother"
#  $ chara   : chr  "hello" "world" "again"
```

From here,

```r
isdate <- type == "Date"
funs <- mget(paste0("as.", type), inherits = TRUE)
str(funs) # list of functions
# List of 4
#  $ as.integer  :function (x, ...)  
#  $ as.Date     :function (x, ...)  
#  $ as.factor   :function (x)  
#  $ as.character:function (x, ...)  

d2[isdate] <- Map(function(f, ...) f(...), funs[isdate], d2[isdate], list(format = "%Y%m%d"))
d2[!isdate] <- Map(function(f, ...) f(...), funs[!isdate], d2[!isdate])
str(d2)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ num     : int  1 2 3
#  $ date    : Date, format: "2021-01-11" "2022-01-22" "2022-03-02"
#  $ relation: Factor w/ 3 levels "brother","father",..: 2 3 1
#  $ chara   : chr  "hello" "world" "again"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `structure()`. Currently your `Date` variable isn't very handy and you need to do `d[[2]] <- as.Date(d[[2]], format='%Y%m%d')` beforehand.

```
r <- structure(Map(\(x, y, z) eval(parse(text=x)), sprintf('as.%s(y)', type), d),
               class="data.frame", 
               row.names=c(NA, -3L), 
               names=nm)

r
#   num       date relation chara
# 1   1 2021-01-11   father hello
# 2   2 2022-01-22   mather world
# 3   3 2022-03-02  brother again

str(r)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ num     : int  1 2 3
# $ date    : Date, format: "2021-01-11" ...
# $ relation: Factor w/ 3 levels "brother","father",..: 2 3 1
# $ chara   : chr  "hello" "world" "again"
```

**Note:** R >= 4.1 used.

---

*Data:*

```
d <- list(c(1, 2, 3),
          c("20210111", "20220122", "20220302"),
          c("father", "mather", "brother"),
          c("hello", "world", "again"))
type <- c("integer", "Date", "factor", "character")
nm <- c("num", "date", "relation", "chara")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution:

```
z <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, d))

colnames(z) <- nm
z$num <- as.integer(z$num)
z$date <- as.Date(z$date, format = "%Y%m%d")
z$relation <- as.factor(z$relation)
z$chara <- as.character(z$chara)
```